# how to store interest rate daily based into database

Tags: php, database, mysqli, cron

please anyone can help me to solve the problem, am new to php development field

am developing investment interest portal, am getting problem to store interest rate daily based into database, the actual problem is to store interest with user details, am using cron job to run function for every 24hours its working perfect but when i am login as user its storing that user's interest rate values only , other user not storing, i think am using session user logged details maybe this problem, please can anyone help me to store every users interest value with user details

```
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['sess_user'];
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "bitmining");

    $investedusername = $_SESSION['sess_user']; 
    $sql3="SELECT sum(inv_amount) as total FROM buyinvest WHERE invested_username='$investedusername'";         

    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql3);           
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){

        $investment = $row['total'];
        $days = 1;
        $interest_rate = (350/100/365) * $days ;
        $finalvalue = $interest_rate * $days;

    } 

    $date = "SELECT invest_timestamp FROM buyinvest ORDER BY invest_timestamp DESC LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $date);
    $d_test = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

    $d_test2 = $d_test["invest_timestamp"];

    $timestamp = time();

    $investeduser = $_SESSION['sess_user'];
    $interestamount = $finalvalue;  
    $date_interest = date("y-m-d h:i:s");

    if ($d_test2  + 86400 == $timestamp){
        if ($conn){
                $sql3 = "INSERT INTO user_investments(invested_user, interest_amount, date_interest) VALUES('$investeduser','$interestamount','$date_interest')";
                if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql3))
                {
                    echo "Updated!";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "There is an error.";
                }
            }
        }
        else {
        echo "Not yet!";
        }
```

please anyone help me to solve above code

Comment: You're just storing the data for single user only if you want to do for all select all the user and run the above code in the loop

Comment: Can you give me example code please

Comment: just fetch all the user and run the query in the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
$sql = "SELECT * from table_name";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0){

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$sql3="SELECT sum(inv_amount) as total FROM buyinvest WHERE invested_username='".$row['username']"'";
// your code
}
}
```